# Select files with same base names using R

Tags: r

Would it be possible to select files with same base names (uniq) from all the files in the directory. I have been able to get the list of all the files from the directory.

```
fastq.files <- list.files(path = rawdatapath, pattern = c("(.fastq.gz|.fq.gz|.fastq|.fq)$"), full.names = TRUE)
fastq.files
```

And the files would be something like this in the directory:

```
t1_R1.fq
t1_R2.fq
t2_R1.fq
t2_R1.fq
```

Here the uniq base name is t1 and t2

The given below is the bash equivalent.

```
#Shell Script:

#!bin/bash

for i in $(ls *.fastq | rev | cut -c 14- | rev | uniq)

do 

bowtie2 --very-sensitive -p16 --rg-id ${i} -x cprefseqs -1 ${i}_R1_001.fastq -2 ${i}_R2_001.fastq  -S $i.sam

done
```

Comment: gonna need some examples of the filenames in question

Answer (score 1):

If your files all have that same format you can use `lapply` and `strsplit` to get all the unique base names

```
x <- file.names()
 [1] "t1_R1.fq" "t1_R2.fq" "t2_R1.fq" "t2_R1.fq"

#splits each string into a list using "_" as a delimiter and returns the first element
f <- lapply(strsplit(x, "_"), "[", 1)

f <- unique(unlist(f))
 [1] "t1" "t2"

res <- lapply(f, function(x) list.files(pattern=x))
```

Comment: Great! If it has worked for you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark